# How can we determine, that we are already in transaction block?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I use exposed without DAO with caffeine cache.
The common usage is

```
transaction {
  val row = rowService.getById(1)!! 
}
```

RowService tries to find row in cache first, if negative, runs query againt database. I suspect that transaction block even without any queries has some overhead and if I cache-hit most of the time, I think to move transaction block in RowService where it resolves data from database, however I don't want to create nested transaction in the process.

How can I check that I'm in transaction block already and re-use it or open new one and run my fetch statementand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default nested `transaction` blocks will reuse the outermost `Transaction` instance.
But if you want to ensure that there is a started `Transaction` from a code you could check it with: `TransactionManager.currentOrNull() != null`

Answer (score 0):

> [Since Exposed 0.16.1 it is possible to use nested transactions. To enable this feature you should set useNestedTransactions on desire Database instance to true.](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/Transactions#using-nested-transactions)

Just don't set `useNestedTransactions` (or better, explicitly set it to `false`) and you'll get the desired behavior.